# Linux VMware 11 guest mesa drivers install to update OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I currently am using VMWARE 11 guest Linux Mint, on a host win 8.1

So i am basically trying to update OpenGL so that i can program with higher versions of GLSL and OpenGL such as 3.3 , as it currently stands when i check with glxinfo | grep OpenGL , i get

$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:

Now i went to Mesa3d website and downloaded the 10.5.6(as you can see above the one i have installed is 10.1.3)in which the OPenGL version has been updated to version 3.3 which is what i would prefer to have over the current version which is 1.2(shading language GLSL) i downloaded the tar , extracted it , ran ./configure as instructed, and it did its thing, ran make as ./configure finished by saying run make now , and finally ran sudo install make which was the last autoconf instruction , and all completed successfully, i even ran them a second time when i found out that glxinfo | grep OpenGL was still giving me the same return as before i "installed" the mesa 3d drivers

so i am trying to find out what is missing here and why this is not installing?

is it because of the fact that i am running a guest OS linux on a host vmware?or is it something less complicated and actually fixable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the system Mesa installation? Because if not you've got two Mesa installations side-by-side and that will not end well. Also when configuring you should select the parts of Mesa you want. Which in your case would be *none* of the GPU drivers and just the softpipe implementation.

Comment: @hopjoppe5: Using `apt-get remove …` passing in the right package names – which I'm not going to tell you. The thing is: It should not be necessary to install a custom version of Mesa, since the softpipe is present in all of them, and if no supported GPU is available (like if running in a VM). What you actually *should* do is creating a custom Mesa package that you can use to replace the default Mesa package of your distribution, through the package manager. Doing otherwise is a recipe for completely wrecking your system so I strongly discourage doing it.